# Is it both mentally and physically healthy for my cat to be kept like this?

Tags: cats, health, psychology

My mom is her late 60's and lonely. She has found as if her child in my cat, Bhutu.

She keeps Bhutu on a leash with the other end of the leash in her hand 24 hours. She even sleeps with the leash in her hand.

Bhutu is a 24 hours lap cat for her. Bhutu mostly sleeps in her laps.

Even in winter she and Bhutu sleeps under same blanket with Bhutu under her belly.

In dawn and dusk she takes Bhutu out for a walk for 30 minutes.

And indeed it seems Bhutu is very happy and contended in her life.

Now it is extremely unlike for cats to adapt to such environment as it is very dog like thing to do.

So is my cat mentally and physically healthy?

Answer (score 3):

Being on a leash isn't necessarily bad, but I'd be concerned that a cat kept on a leash all the time would not be able to take care of its needs. Like any other animal, it needs to be able to eat, drink, exercise, and relieve itself freely. I'm especially concerned about drinking and relieving itself because cats can be prone to UTIs and kidney problems, which are made worse if the cat is not taking care of its basic needs as it should.

As for the question of staying on her lap most of the day, cats in the general spend a great portion of their day sleeping, and cats of certain temperaments will be content to even laze around all day. It's very unlikely that the cat could be made to do this if it weren't already inclined to. Cats would generally squirm and try to escape if they didn't. However, some attempt should be made to play with the cat even just a small amount every day, as all animals get many benefits from exercise. In the end though, this may not be very possible for some cats who are too much of a couch potato to get moving, and you can't exactly force a cat to do anything.

In conclusion, I think it's likely the cat is probably happy with this lifestyle as long as it can freely take care of its other needs, and as long as it's getting some decent exercise in the form of walks, it is probably okay.

Comment: I don't know how, but for all her needs she makes noises, each noise for a particular need, and my mom seems to be able to understand it. Also if my mom is sleeping at night, the cat licks my mom on nose to wake up her

Comment: Ans my other question staying on human lap instead of pillow, is it okay?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong about taking the cat for walks but cats do need to take some breaks during a walk. As long as one walks slowly and keep an eye on the cat and stops if it gets tired, there is no problem.

One should never force the cat to take walks, so if she resists, you need to stop doing it.

Your cat is an indoor cat and she might like to get some of her energy out of her system. Some exercise can only be positive and the cat will be a lot more calm after the walks, so this is good physically and mentally for your cat.

You should take the leash off when it is not needed inside the house,A ad if the cat likes the walks she will understand that when she see the harness she will be taken for a walk.